# Consider a recursive sequence. Find all values of x for which this sequence is bounded

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Consider a recursive sequence $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 2$ with $a_{1} = 1$ and $a_2 = x$. Find all values of $x$ for which this sequence is bounded.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Newcomers, especially young ones,should  also  be encouraged to  search the suggested list that is offered to them when they are posing and writing the Q.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the duplicate question, because I can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that (similarly to the Fibonacci sequence) all such sequences must satisfy
$$a_n=\alpha \cdot a^n+\beta \cdot b^n$$ where $a,b$ are the roots of $x^2-x-1=0$ i.e. $a=\frac{1 +\sqrt{5}}{2},b=\frac{1 -\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
Since $|b|<1$ but $|a|>1$ it is necessary (and sufficient) for the sequence to be bounded to satisfy $\alpha=0$.
So $a_n=\beta b^n$ i.e. $\beta=\frac{1}{b}$ (by the condition $a_1=1$) and so $x=a_2=b=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the unique solution.